# How comments similar to <summary></summary> from C# should be used in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

Is there any solution in to make comments before each method in Obj C code similar to from  from C#? I'd like to provide an information about my custom methods by Alt + Double mouse click when browsing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In objective-c doesn't exists a standard way to comment your code.
I can suggest you to use doxygen, doxygen use a syntax similar to JavaDoc and can generate Docset that xcode can load and use for suggestion.
I understand that this isn't trivial like in C# but for a brief introdution about Doxygen syntax, Usefull script and how to generate Xcode docset take a look at:

- http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-i/
- http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-ii

Answer (score 2):

there is none, no Summary , no Regions